# What's the most efficient way to implement this 3-column responsive layout with custom wrapping rules?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

At first this looks like a standard 3-column layout, but the way the auxiliary columns wrap isn't common and doesn't seem to fit flexbox's wrapping model, either in forward or reverse mode. Perhaps grid is a better solution than flexbox? I'd like to avoid media queries if possible, but of course a working solution is better than none.

[image: 3-column layout with querky wrapping rules]

### Design constraints

- When there is enough space (1200px), all columns display adjacent with fixed widths.
- When there is only enough room for *MAIN* and *AUX1* (1000px), *AUX2* wraps beneath and fills the width.
- When there is only enough room for *MAIN* (800px), both auxiliary columns wrap beneath and sit adjacent to each other at 50% width.
- As the screen continues to shrink, the layout remains the same as per 800px, but all columns shrink proportionally without overflowing the screen bounds.
- None of the three content areas can overlap or intersect.

Comment: This looks exactly what media queries were made for.  Why not use them?

Comment: @John They're harder to maintain and less flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created this just for you :).

EDIT: Here is a new way of doing it with a grid which will form to the content added to the divs.  Please let me know if this works.

```css
.contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap{
   display: inline-flex;
}

.aux2{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.main{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
   display: inline-flex;
}

.aux1{
  background-color: green;
   width: 200px;
    display: inline-flex;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px){
  .wrap{
   display: grid;
   justify-items: center;
   grid-template-areas: auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.aux2{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.main{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
   display: inline-flex;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.aux1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
   grid-row: 1;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .wrap{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.aux2{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.main{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
   display: inline-flex;
   grid-row: 1;
   grid-column: 1 /span 2;
}

.aux1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="aux2">aux2</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="aux1">aux1</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is just a visual trick, as one can see if filling containers with content and/or adding borders. Any solution incorporating absolute positioning should be considered invalid. That is, the content areas are overlapping.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions  I have added a new method to my answer using a grid.  Please take a look and let me know if this works for you.